# Getting multiple numbers from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I have the following string:

```
var string = "((52.33962959999999, 13.09116629999994), (52.6754542, 13.761117600000034))"
```

which I want to convert into an array, object, or anything to easily get to each of the numbers separately.

Right now, I'm using:

```
string = string.split('(').join('');
string = string.split(')').join('');
string = string.split(', ');
```

which gives me a one-dimensional array of the four numbers.

Is there not a nicer, easier way? One that would give me a multi-dimensional array, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var arrayString = string.replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']');
var numberArray = JSON.parse(arrayString);
```

This replaces all `(` with `[` and `)` with `]`. Now you can parse it as a JavaScript object.

Output would be a two dimensional array, just as your notation.

Comment: This is *probably* better than what poster asked for, although poster's answer will return these as strings, so if that's what poster needs, this'd need to be massaged a bit.

Comment: IF he have control of the formatting of the input string he could use json notation an avoid the `replace`s.